# C# MVC strongly typed view with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a *ViewModel* called `MyViewModel` which contains:

```
public IList<Config> Config { get; set; }
public bool Disabled { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Config is a object which contains `ID` & `Value`

on the Controller side I'm populating all the values and in the view i need to access this List of Config individual items where `id = x` and it should display corresponding value in label. so i need a strongly typed label for this something along the lines of:

```
@Html.LabelFor(a => ....)
```

I'm not sure about what should be my Linq statement to display Config.Value in label where `Config.Id = x`. any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: If you only need to access `Config`'s where `id=x` why not just filter the collection to include only those items before passing the view model to the view?

Comment: I want to have multiple labels & next will be with Config value where id=y

Comment: Then you would need something like `@foreach(var item in Model.Config.Where(i => i.ID == "x")) { ....`

Comment: Also are you confusing `LabelFor()` with `DisplayFor()`? `LabelFor()` will return the name of the property (i.e. "Value"), not its value

Comment: actually LabelFor or DisplayFor either will work. Just need to display whichever i pick out of group by id at a time. foreach will force me to go in a specific order which i do not want

Comment: As I noted above `LabelFor(m => m.Value)` will always display the text `"Value"` so I think you actually want `DisplayFor()`. It not really clear what you trying to display. Perhaps include a few sample items and the output your expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To display table grouped by ID values, first create a list of all existing Id numbers.

```
ViewBag.Ids = Config.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct(); //create list of all existing Ids
```

Pass that list into your View via the ViewBag, and iterate through it as well as your list of objects:

```
@foreach(int IdNum in ViewBag.Ids)
{
    <table>
    @foreach(Config c in Config.Where(x=> x.Id == IdNum))
    {
        <tr>  
          <td> @c.ID </td>
          <td> @c.property1 </td>
          <td> @c.property2 </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
```

In this case, I wouldn't bother with the LabelFor() method, since it is easy enough to just use the shorthand @object.property inline with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

to display a list by group try this

```
<table>
     @{

      foreach (var group in Model.Config.GroupBy(x => x.Id))
      {
    <tr>  
      <td>@group.Key</td> </tr>
      int index =0;
@foreach(Config c in Model.Config.Where(x=> x.Id == group.Key))
{
    <tr>  
      <td> @Model.Config[index].ID </td>
      <td> @Model.Config[index].property1 </td>
      <td> @Model.Config[index].property2 </td>
    </tr>
index++;
}

      }
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping over it & trying few times I finally got it. This is what I was looking for:

```
@Html.Label(Model.Config.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConfigId == "x").Value)
```

For some reason though, it won't work on @Html.Display. Any idea why? Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.